# Elasticsearch ILM index data is not shifting/migrating

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud, elasticsearch-indices, ilm

We have created ILM (index lifecycle management) policies, to automate index rollover using a matching index template and a bootstrap index to enable write index with an alias.

Please find the below API code:

Polices

```
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "min_age": "0ms",
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_size": "50mb",
            "max_primary_shard_size": "50mb",
            "max_age": "30m"
          },
          "set_priority": {
            "priority": 200
          }
        }
      },
      "cold": {
        "min_age": "5m",
        "actions": {
          "searchable_snapshot": {
            "snapshot_repository": "found-snapshots",
            "force_merge_index": true
          },
          "set_priority": {
            "priority": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "frozen": {
        "min_age": "10m",
        "actions": {
          "searchable_snapshot": {
            "snapshot_repository": "found-snapshots",
            "force_merge_index": true
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "1h",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {
            "delete_searchable_snapshot": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Template

```
PUT _index_template/sree
{
"index_patterns":["sree-*"],
"template":{
"settings":{
"number_of_shards":1,
"number_of_replicas":1,
"index.lifecycle.name":"sree",
"index.lifecycle.rollover_alias":"sree"
}
}
}
```

Bootstrap Index:

```
PUT sree-000001
{
"aliases":{
"sree":{
"is_write_index":true
}
}
}
```

**Note:** I'm using logstash to send data to elastic search by using the elasticsearch output plugin.

Here is the output plugin code:

```
output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "https:xyz:9243"
                user => "elastic"
                password => "xyz"
                index => "sree-"
                ilm_enabled => true
        }
    
}
```

For the above scenario, I'm successfully creating index and index-alias, indexes are moving to next nodes like cold/frozen but data is not shifting/migrating.

So, can anyone please help us to resolve this issue?[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "data is not shifting/migrating"?

Comment: @val index is shifting to the next phases but data is not loading to any of those indices.

Comment: All indices are showing 0 documents... so probably nothing is being loaded by Logstash. I would start investigating there

Comment: I am getting error 'illegal_argument_exception: index.lifecycle.rollover_alias[sree] doesnot point to index[sree-2021.08.04]'

Comment: your write index is called `sree` but your output in Logstash is `sree-`, is that a typo?

Comment: @MarkWalkom I am getting similar error 'illegal_argument_exception:'  after removing '-' also